# How to assert data saved in mongomock?

Tags: pytest, mongomock

Below is the function for saving data in Mongo.

```
def _save(data):
    db_client = DBConnect().client
    try:
        db = db_client[os.environ['DB']]
        table = db['Table']
        table.insert_many([data], ordered=False)
    except Exception as err:
        log.error(err)
    finally:
        db_client.close()
```

I am testing this function.

I wrote test case like this

```
@pytest.fixture
def client_mock():
    yield mongomock.MongoClient()

@pytest.fixture(autouse=False)
def patch_mongo(monkeypatch, client_mock):
    mock_client = client_mock
    db = mock_client['DB']
    col = db['Table']

    def fake_mongo():
        return mock_client.db
    monkeypatch.setattr('address.DBConnect', fake_mongo)
```

Now the testcase

```
def test_save(patch_mongo, client_mock):
    data = {'1':[1, 2, 3]}
    k = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'DB': 'DB'})
    k.start()
    x = _save(data)
    k.stop()
```

the data is successfully inserted, now i want to assert the db contains this data.
Can anyone help?